# awk array to output the line count as well as average

Tags: awk

Thanks to @karakfa the below `awk` array results in the output. I am trying to add `$2` to the array and output that as well.  `$2` is basically the amount of times the unique entry appears. As I am leaaring `awk` arrays I do not know if my attempt is close.

Input:

```
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 1   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 2   0
chr1:985542-985763  AGRN:exon.2 1   0
chr1:985542-985763  AGRN:exon.2 2   1
```

My script:

```
awk '{k=$1 OFS $2;
    l=$2;  # Is this correct?
    s[k]+=$4; c[k]++}
  END{for(i in s)  # Is this correct?
    print i, s[i]/c[i]},
      "(lbases)"  # Is this correct?' input
```

Current output:

```
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.1 0
chr1:985542-985763 AGRN:exon.2 0.5
```

Desired output:

```
chr1:955542-955763 AGRN:exon.1 0   (2 bases)
chr1:985542-985763 AGRN:exon.2 0.5 (2 bases)
```

Comment: pluse-uno for input, desired output, current output and code!!! Keep posting and good luck!

Comment: Do you understand what/how the original awk script worked? Because without that doing what you want is going to be a good bit harder. (Specifically that attempt stores exactly **one** value for `l` and doesn't include the variable in the output correctly.)

Comment: I edited your script and took out an obvious syntax error in the process.  You still have somewhat grave errors in your script, but now, at least it's runnable.

Comment: The way I understand the `awk` (before my attempt) is that `$1` is stored as k and the unique value in `$2`  defines the lines used to calculate the average from `$4`.  Am I close?  Thank you :).

Comment: one of awk's weakness's is lack of debugging support (Maybe others will correct me). So you need to learn to debug using statements like `print "NR="NR "\tNF="NF"\tValueForVar_k="k "\tValForVar_l=" l `. Then you'll easily see the flow of data into and out of your script. (Use small files for testing!). Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt to introduce a new variable is not going to work.  You need a count per array key, so the variable should be another array.  But in this case, you don't need to add a new array, because the array `c` already contains the count per key.

```
awk '{k=$1 OFS $2;
    s[k]+=$4; c[k]++}
  END{for(i in s)
    print i, s[i]/c[i], c[i] " bases" }' input
```

Notice also how your attempt unhappily had the "bases" outside the closing brace of the `END` block.

This differs from the problem description in that the key is not `$2`, but the combination of `$1` and `$2`.  If you genuinely need the key to be solely `$2`, you do need a new array, but then the whole thing will get quite a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you very much, works great :) and thank you for your explanation :).